# How speed up single frame webcam capturing in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I need a way to capture one and just one frame every N seconds. I presumed, that all need is to create `VideoCapture` object with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` and call `_, frame = cap.read()` every N seconds.

But, as appeared, `VideoCapture` has it's own buffer, which set to 4 by default. It means, that I must call `cap.read` 4 time, before I'll get frame from another timespan.

I figured out, that I am able to shrink buffer size with `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)`, but it cannot be 0. It means, that I still need to drop 1 frame before I'll get the one I need.

Besides that such solution is a crotch, each call of `cap.read()` is pretty slow -- 68 ms on my machine -- and I need to call it twice each time.

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)

### read() is actually grab() + retrieve()

########## Tests

# %%timeit
# 68 ms ± 30.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# video.read()

# %%timeit
# 68 ms ± 51.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# video.grab()
# video.retrieve()

# %%timeit
# 68 ms ± 2.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# video.grab()

# %%timeit
# 134 ms ± 4.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# video.grab()
# video.grab()

# %%timeit
# 1.06 s ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# video = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
# video.read()
# video.release()
##########

def frame_generator(video):
    while (video.isOpened()):
        video.grab()
        video.grab()
        success, frame = video.retrieve()
        if success:
            yield frame
        else:
            yield False


gen_frame = frame_generator(cap)

# %%timeit
# 136 ms ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# next(gen_frame)
```

- Is there a way to get rid of that buffer at all?
- Is there a way to grap frames from webcam faster, maybe with other packages/libs?

Comment: Not sure I understand why 68ms per frame is a problem when you only want to grab one frame every N seconds?

Comment: Hm, good point. Maybe I just was rudely surprised, when discovered that frame grepping takes more time than processing it through MobileNet NN on CPU (it actually takes 68*2 ms to get the frame I need). But what should I do if I'll need to run it faster than 7 fps (68*2*7 = 952 ms)?